# Is inheritance in Data Transfer Objects a bad practice?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Would flattening dtos be an approach that makes client code easier to write? Whats is the best practice here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of DTOs is to transfer data in a structured way. Inheritance tends to get in the way of that when trying to establish a data contract between client and server. You can do it, but it tends to be painful.

I recommend you go with aggregation instead.